# How to set acl on a file in remote website using msdeploy & powershell/psake

Tags: iis, powershell

I am running a build process in powershell and using msdeploy to deploy a website to a remote server. I need to set acls on a particular file either when the site is deployed or post deployment.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`setAcl provider`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569047%28v=WS.10%29.aspx). You'll need to swap to use a `manifest` provider for the source:

```
<customManifest>
    <!-- or whatever your web app source is -->
    <iisApp path="Default Web Site" />

    <setAcl path="Default Web Site\web.config" 
            setAclUser="ApplicationPoolIdentity"
            setAclAccess="Write" 
            setAclResourceType="File" />
</customManifest>
```